# How to access DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE with instance of Mage_Core_Model_Resource?

Tags: magento-enterprise, core

I'm trying to set set a DATETIME field in my model to `NOW()` using Magento's RDBMS abstractions with[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13836895/1149718)]:

```
/** @var $adapter Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface **/
$now = $adapter->formatDate(Varien_Date::now())
// or
$nowDateOnlyWithoutTime = $adapter->formatDate(Varien_Date::now(), false)
```

However, I need to get a handle on that `$adapter` first.  I'm trying to do this (with annotations):

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
#=> instance of Mage_Core_Model_Resource

Mage::log("get read connection: [{$resource->DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE}]");
#=> get read connection: []

$adapter = $resource->getConnection($resource->DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE);
```

So my question is, how do I access `DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE`?

I have `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php` open, and it defines the constant as `const DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE = 'core_read';`, yet I get an empty string in my code.

With all this MVC bs bloating Magento's code, it appears I'm supposed to access class constants through instances rather than hardcoded class names--in case someone, somewhere, sometime overrides the constant in a subclass and hooks the subclass in as a replacement.

I know I can use a number of alternatives here: `Mage_Core_Model_Resource::DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE`, or even `'core_read'`.  But these seem counter to Magento's MVC conventions.

[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13836895/1149718)]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13836895/1149718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should use the `::` operator instead of `->`.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
#=> instance of Mage_Core_Model_Resource

Mage::log("get read connection: [" . $resource::DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE . "]");
#=> get read connection: [core_read]

$adapter = $resource->getConnection($resource::DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE);
```

Crap.  I've been banging my head against so many issues with Magento extension development, I automatically assumed this was another issue with Magento.  It's not.

It's an issue with PHP and my lack of familiarity with its nuances.  Once I considered this, the answer took minutes to find[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976806/cannot-access-class-constant-from-an-instance-using-the-scope-operator)].

[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976806/cannot-access-class-constant-from-an-instance-using-the-scope-operator)] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976806/cannot-access-class-constant-from-an-instance-using-the-scope-operator

Answer (score 0):

To get the default connection you can use the constants defined in the class `Mage_Core_Model_Resource`

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection(Mage_Core_Model_Resource::DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE);
```

There are default resources for read, write and setup.

```
const DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE  = 'core_read';
const DEFAULT_WRITE_RESOURCE = 'core_write';
const DEFAULT_SETUP_RESOURCE = 'core_setup';
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I'm already aware that `Mage_Core_Model_Resource::DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE` is possible, but is not consistent with the way Magento uses MVC.  I've found and posted the answer I expected.  Update your answer to the same solution, and you've got yourself another check.

Comment: It has nothing to do with MVC but is just class constants. Both answers work fine in php 5.3 upwards. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php